# Bash Pattern for starting an app and waiting until it loads/completes before next step

Tags: bash, idioms

So there is a common problem that I have found in bash. Let's say you start a program X and you want to either wait until it has completed or until it has loaded before initiating program Y. What is the pattern for doing this?

---

Just thinking... I guess you could do `X && Y` in the case that you're waiting for X to complete. But I still don't know about what to do in order to determine if the program X has "loaded". (And I know I'm using "loaded" very generically here, so tell me if I need to be more specific.)

---

Loaded - should mean that the program has reached "the state" that I'm looking for and has somehow left evidence, for instance by creating a "loaded" file as a token (which it will presumably remove upon shutdown). So how then do I check in bash to see if that token exists. Do I write a while look that checks for it's existence indefinitely and then completes only upon finding the "loaded" token?

Comment: "Loaded" could mean a lot of things; some of them are not reliably distinguishable (for example, unless the program itself provides one there is no way to reliably identify a new X11 window as belonging to a particular program name).

Comment: I'm still a little confused.  Are you wanting to leave a 'loaded' token so that some other process can be kicked off while process X completes (i.e. parallel processing)?  If not, I would do what my answer suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just call something like `X && checkIfXLoaded && Y`?

Comment: maybe - check my new addition to the question